# Trying to simplify complicated regex

Tags: java, regex, perl

For example, the following regex attempts to account for all possible, valid non-military **time intervals**.  As in: "04-12:15", "12:30-9", "3:10-4:57", but won't match anything from say:

`"<td class="text">2013-11-04</td>"`.

Regex (from another similar question credit to @MikeClark for regex):

```
regex = "(?<!\\d|-|:)((?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])(?::[0-5][0-9])?-
                      (?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])(?::[0-5][0-9])?)(?!\\d|-|:)"
```

Here's an explanation of the regex:

`(?<!\\d|-|:)` Negative look-behind for number, hyphen or colon
`(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])` Accounts for all valid hours
`(?::[0-5][0-9])` Accounts for all valid minutes
`(?!\\d|-|:)` Negative look-ahead for number, hyphen or colon

Hopefully the rest is self explanatory.  This works, but it's quite verbose.  In theory, this can be simplified to:
Let EXP = `(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])(?:[0-5][0-9])?`

```
"(?<!\\d|-|:)((?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])(?::[0-5][0-9])?-EXP)(?!\\d|-|:)";
```

**So my questions are:**

**(1)**:
Is there any way to reference part of a regular expression?  Back-referencing won't work because it's not what the expression matches that I want (assuming that it was a capturing group), but the expression, itself.  I understand that one can store the expression in a String and use `format()`, but I'm looking to see if one can do this solely in the regex.

**(2)**:
The only other thing that I can think of that would help is being able to determine which repetition that one is in in an expression.  As in:

Given: `regex = "...(?:someExpression){2}"`

Is there a way to determine if we are in the 1<sup>st</sup> or 2<sup>nd</sup> repetition of `someExpression`?

Answers pertaining to `Java` or `Perl` would be best for me.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Is there any way to reference part of a regular expression?` ?

Yes, it is. You can use the notation `(?1)` in order to reuse the first definition group. In your case it is:

```
(?<!\d|-|:)(((?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])(?::[0-5][0-9])?)-(?2))(?!\d|-|:)
```

You have to make one more group.

Comment: Thanks I forgot about recursive patterns in perl (for reference it's only `\d`).  Of course, I now realize that the regex given is actually incorrect. :(

Comment: Okay, everything is fixed (I updated your answer and my question), but as I expected, it worked!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Probably the shortest/simplet version:

package snippets;

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.junit.Test;

public class RegexTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(0?[0-9]|1[0-2])(:[0-5][0-9])?-(0?[0-9]|1[0-2])(:[0-5][0-9])?");
        assertFalse(p.matcher("0").matches());
        assertFalse(p.matcher("1:00").matches());
        assertFalse(p.matcher("9:59").matches());
        assertFalse(p.matcher("10:01").matches());
        assertFalse(p.matcher("12").matches());

        assertTrue(p.matcher("04-12:15").matches());
        assertTrue(p.matcher("12:30-9").matches());
        assertTrue(p.matcher("3:10-4:57").matches());

        assertFalse(p.matcher("9:6").matches());
        assertFalse(p.matcher("9:60").matches());
        assertFalse(p.matcher("13").matches());
        assertFalse(p.matcher("20").matches());
        assertFalse(p.matcher("20:").matches());
        assertFalse(p.matcher("20-").matches());
        assertFalse(p.matcher(":20").matches());
        assertFalse(p.matcher("-20").matches());
    }

}
```

To your questions:

(1) As far as I know not in that way you need. Backreferences expectes the same value as first time. http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html

(2) Not as far as i know.

Comment: You misunderstood the question.  Single times should not be matched. The point here is to match time intervals.

Comment: Only time intervals? It matches time intervals, too.

Comment: Yes, only time intervals.

Comment: That's not correct.  With that logic, you're eventually going to get to the regex that I have.  The reason that I asked the question was to be able to simplify that regex.  The two questions that I asked, if possible, will help to do that.  Yours for example fails on your own input: "3:10-4:57".  Additionally, think about something like: `"<td class=\"text\">2013-11-04</td>"`, which shouldn't match at all.

Comment: 1. The unittest fails, if you run it?!? 
2. "2013-11-04" don't match the pattern I used.
3. You read my answers to your questions?

Comment: I probably don't understand what you want - sorry.

Comment: It's no biggie.  Thanks for trying.